# Is there any phonegap 3.4 plugin available for the text to speech conversion in android,iPhone & Blackberry

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I wants to know is there any plugin available for text to speech conversion which will work in android ,iphone and blackberry. I am using phonegap 3.4.0 and in my current project i need to do the text to speech conversion in all the three platforms. I dont want to develope the code seperatelly for each platform.. Please help me

Thanks & Regards,
Johncy Binoy

Comment: http://jquer.in/helpful-jquery-plugins-for-html5-websites/speak-js/     check this

Comment: and also try this    http://www.anil2u.info/2013/01/jquery-plugin-for-text-to-speech/